# WM_PAINT stops working after minimizing and restoring the window

Tags: c++, winapi

I've made a program with a custom non-client area. Instead of handling WM_NCPAINT, i set the client area size to zero in WM_NCCALCSIZE and then simulate the non-client area by handling WM_NCHITTEST. All painting to the window is handled in WM_PAINT. WM_PAINT works fine when i start the program and whenever the program needs repainted. However, once i minimize the program with a call to ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE), and then restore the program by clicking on it in the task bar, WM_PAINT no longer works. I've checked every function call in WM_PAINT and they all return success, but the window just shows up as black. Anybody have any ideas as to why?

Here's the code for my WM_PAINT handler:

http://pastebin.com/MXmWzb4M

Here's the output to the console window:

> BeginPaint successful
>
> hdcBuffer is valid
>
> MainWindow->hbmBuffer is valid
>
> hdcMem is valid

So, seeing as every function call in my WM_PAINT handler is returning success, why is my entire window showing up as black?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `WM_NCPAINT` in that case?

Comment: @pezcode it doesn't really matter that much, as both handlers do basically the same thing.

Comment: I've solved this problem, i'll add the answer in 6-7 hours when stackoverflow will let me >_<

Comment: Unusual way to do this.  Much simpler is to just omit the WS_CAPTION style flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with handling the WM_NCCALCSIZE message to remove the non-client area. Here's the alternative that i used:

```
        DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
        dwStyle &= ~WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);
```

Comment: You'll want to use `GetWindowLongPtr` and `SetWindowLongPtr` for future 64-bit compatibility.

Comment: The non-Ptr version is fine for styles (GWL_*STYLE) but it is probably easy to make a C&P error so switching to SetWindowLongPtr is good advice...

Comment: Ah i see. I'll keep that in mind for future reference, thanks for pointing that out. ^_^